# Accessing the Google Documents List API from Ruby

Tags: ruby, api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to figure out how to access the Google Documents List API from Ruby.

I've looked at the [google-api-ruby-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/) but that doesn't seem to support that particular API. I've also looked at the [gdata-ruby-util](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-ruby-util/) client but that looks like it's out of date and no longer active.

It seems odd that there's no ruby client for accessing such a popular API, so can anyone help with a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a library that lets you read/write files. It also has methods to read/write spreadsheets cells.

https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-ruby-util/ is the correct library.

I would say it is more "stable" than "no longer active".

Comment: I looked at that library but it doesn't seem to support oauth2 unless I'm missing something. Now I'm leaning towards the oauth2 gem. https://github.com/intridea/oauth2

Comment: Being able to access Google Documents List with Ruby/OAuth2 would be great.. I don't see it happening though.